# Access both class instance and jQuery's this with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm implementing a basic "shopping Cart" where you can change product and it recalculates the total price.

I would like to access **both** the instance **and** jQuery's *this* instance within the same method, in particular *product_change()*.

```
class Cart
  constructor: ->
    @bind_listeners()
  bind_listeners: ->
    $('td.product').on 'change', 'select',@product_change
  update_prices: ->
    # For each row of items get span.subtotal and sum
    # Replace content of "total" field with result
  product_change: ->
    # Get new product's price. I need jQ's 'this'
    new_price = $(this).find ':selected'
    # Replace subtotal field
    $('span.subtotal').html new_price
    # Update all prices. I need instance's 'this'
    @update_prices()
```

My working solution right now is to call *update_prices* as another binded method to the `change` event, using fat arrow `=>`. However I'd rather have a prettier alternative.

```
class Cart
  constructor: ->
    @bind_listeners()
  bind_listeners: ->
    $('td.product').on 'change', 'select',@product_change
    # Call update_prices here
    $('td.product').on 'change', 'select',@update_prices
  update_prices: ->
    # For each row of items get span.subtotal and sum
    # Replace content of "total" field with result
  product_change: ->
    # Get new product's price. I need jQ's 'this'
    new_price = $(this).find ':selected'
    # Replace subtotal field
    $('span.subtotal').html new_price
    # Update all prices. I need instance's 'this'
    #@update_prices()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the value of `this` that jQuery sets when it calls an event handler, use the target jQuery passes to the event handler. They're both the same object: The DOM element that triggered the event.

So your code becomes:

```
class Cart
  constructor: ->
    @bind_listeners()
  bind_listeners: ->
    $('td.product').on 'change', 'select', @product_change.bind(@)
  update_prices: ->
    # For each row of items get span.subtotal and sum
    # Replace content of "total" field with result
  product_change: (e) ->
    # Get new product's price. I need jQ's 'this'
    new_price = $(e.currentTarget).find ':selected'
    # Replace subtotal field
    $('span.subtotal').html new_price
    @update_prices()
```

(Note that I've used `.bind` to prevent the value of `this` from being overridden when jQuery calls `product_change`. You could, alternatively, define the method with `=>` to accomplish the same thing.)

Using `this` in methods to consistently refer to the object those methods are attached to, rather than something else, will make your life as a CoffeeScripter much easier.

Comment: What version of jQuery is this? jQuery passes the `event` object as the first param; you can get the target from the event object...?

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks. Your advice about *this* usage makes a lot of sense to me, thanks! However, regarding the use of `=>` to accomplish the same thing as `.bind`, I guess I'd need to pass the jquery object to the `product_change` method? e.g. `$('td.product').on 'change', 'select', product_change($('td.product select'))`. So that in the scope of the method, `e` equals the DOM element?

Comment: @vint-i-vuit Sorry, the confusion is my fault. You want to use `e`, the event object that jQuery passes as the first argument to the event handler. That has the DOM element that triggered the `change` event attached, as `e.target`/`e.currentTarget`.

Comment: Sorry I'm insisting, but I don't see it totally clear. How would I access the event object that jQ passes as the first argument to the event handler at that point in the code? ie. When I'm binding a method to an event happening.

Comment: @vint-i-vuit You don't have to pass the jQuery object (`$('td.product select')`) in to the event handler, because you can create a new jQuery object that wraps around the same DOM element with `$(e.currentTarget)` within the event handler. `e`—the first arg passed to the event handler—is an event object, as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: If you really want to use the same jQuery object (to prevent the small performance cost of creating a new one with `$(e.currentTarget)`), you could instead attach that object as a property on the `Cart` instance. So for instance, if you set `@$select = $('td.product select')` in `bind_listeners`, then you could use `@$select` within `product_change`.